# Python combined key entry detection - ESC and Enter

Tags: python, keyboard

In the doDebuggingMenu function below, I am getting the user input using the raw_input function (using Python 2.6). This function waits until the user enters a char sequence and presses enter. Neverthless, I would like to allow the user to exit the application by simply pressing the ESC button in the keyboard without having to press enter (Please see the last elif block in the function where I intend to implement this behaviour). For other menu options the user should be able to press the enter button because there are options in the menu that requires entering a two digit number. My question here is how can I provide this combined behaviour in the following function? Thanks

```
def doDebugingMenu():
    while(1):
        printDebugingMenu()

        char = raw_input("\nPlease, enter your selection in the debugging menu...:")       

        if  char == '1':
           doSetTraceLevelManually()   
        elif  char == '2':
           doSetTraceDomain() 
        elif  char == '3':
           doPrintLevels()                                            
        elif  char == '4':
           doPrintConfig()
        elif  char == '5':
           doPrintProfile()
        elif  char == '6':
           doPrintMap()
        elif  char == '7':
          doPrintCounters()
        elif(char == '8'):
          doRaiseAlarm()
        elif(char == '9'):
          doClearAlarm()       
        elif(char == '10'):
          doUpdateAlarm()
        elif(char == '11'):
          doShutdown()         
        #HERE I need to catch if ESC pressed            
        elif  char == 'ESC':
          break  

def printDebugingMenu():
       print "\n######################################"
       print "#                MENU                 #"
       print "######################################"
       print "1.  setTraceLevel( traceLevel )"
       print "2.  setTraceDomain()"
       print "3.  PRINT Trace Domain and levels"  
       print "4.  PRINT config"
       print "5.  PRINT profile config"
       print "6.  PRINT mapping config"
       print "7.  PRINT counters"  
       print "8.  Issue Alarm"
       print "9.  Remove Alarm"
       print "10. Update Alarm" 
       print "11. Shutdown" 
       print "EXIT: press ESC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input()` is not what you need.

You need to process input character by character so you can detect `ESC`, function keys, etc. Maybe build your own input function that returns the text when you press ENTER but throws exceptions on other keys, but then you need to process backspaces, cursor movements, etc. You can find primitives in the `curses` module on Unices or `msvcrt` on Windows. It's a lot of work. But then you have it and it's reusable if you are writing lots of console based programs.

Normally, though, users are quite content to just use `Ctrl-C` if they want to exit the program and there is no need to complicate things. If you want something fancy write a GUI program. Up to you.

On a side note, that `if` ... `elif` ... `elif` block looks horribly non-pythonic. Take a look at  [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).

Comment: I am relatively new to Python and thanks for the link. The thing is the menu in the above program actually should return to the main menu in case ESC is button so the application does not really quit at this point. I was normally asking for typing 'm' to go back to the main menu but users think it is more convenient to simply press the ESC button to go one level up into the main menu. I wish there would be a build in API to do this job shortly but it looks I need to write a custom code.

Comment: Ha! if you are dealing with users that 'would prefer' ESC over 'm' make sure you are being paid by the hour! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that to do that you'll have to use the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/curses.html) module, but I wouldn't advice it for your simple application.

Also note that `if/elif` switch in Python are usually done with `dict`s.